# NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle number formatter without decimal digits

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I want a price rounded up to be displayed as a currency without digits after the decimal symbol. Without the currency style there is no problem. Is the currency style overriding other properties I set?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After you set the currency style, try

```
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
```

You may need to set the rounding mode as well.

Comment: It seems to be working correct now.
Strange enough I've tried this before and it did not work. Not sure I had both rounding mode and max fraction digits than